# Improve query performance and maintainability

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, count

I have a query like this:

```
select Table1.column1 AS CODE, COUNT(DINSTINCT(Table2.column1 || '|' || Table2.column2)) AS COUNT
FROM   Table2
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
WHERE
....
AND Table1.column1 <> ''
```

The output of the query will be something like this, basically a CODE and the respective COUNT, for example:

```
CODE    COUNT
ref002   3
ref003   1
```

After this first query, I have a `foreach` that will iterate the result of the query above. Inside the `foreach`, for each result of the query
above, I want to get some information that is available in Table3, basically, I want all the values in the Table3.column1 for each CODE (Table1.Column1). So inside the `foreach` I have another query to get the Table3.column for each iterated result:

```
select Table3.column1
FROM   Table3
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
WHERE .... 
AND Table1.column1 = (equal to a parameter (Table1.column1) that is available in each foreach iteration)
```

And like this, I can get all the `Table3.column1` values for each Table1.column1 (for each CODE) of the first query.

**Doubt**

Both queries are almost the same. The only difference between the query before the `foreach` and the query inside the foreach is in the `SELECT` part and in the `WHERE`, basically the where just have an additional condition. So it doesn't seem very good in terms of performance and maintainability has the 2 queries because both queries are almost the same. So it should be possible to get all the necessary information in the first query instead of having a second query inside the `foreach`.

Do you know what is necessary to change in the first query to, besides return the CODE and COUNT, also return all values in the Table3.column1 for each CODE? So that is possible to remove the query inside the foreach and get everything that is needed only one query (the 1st query)? The necessary output for the first query should be something like:

```
CODE     COUNT     IDNUMBERS
ref002    3         ab00, cd00
ref003    1         ef00
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strategy generates one query per code, plus one for the initial query, so that's indeed inefficient.

One simple option would be use a string aggregation function in the original query to generate the additional column.

In Oracle, you can use `listagg()` for this:

```
select 
    t1.column1 as code, 
    count(distinct t2.column1 || '|' || t2.column2) as cnt,
    listagg(t3.column1) idnumbers
from   table2 t2
inner join table3 t3 on t3.referencecolumn = t2.referencecolumn
inner join table1 t1 on t1.referencecolumn = t1.referencecolumn
where ...
group by t1.column1
```

`listagg()` has various option for formating, duplicate management and sorting - you can find the details [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's also possible to achieve a solution for this case using a subquery in the select clause?

Comment: @John: yes, that is possible too; I wrote the query as I did because your original query  involved `table3` already, so it was straight-forward to just add a column.

Comment: Because I'm not understanding how with that listagg solution the t3.column1 values will be associated with the respective CODE (t1.column1). It seems that only with listaggg(t3.column1) it will gaet all the t3.column1 values but it should only bring for each row the t3.column1 values that correspond to each individual CODE. Hm, but maybe is the group by that guarantees this part, no?

Comment: @John: that's what `group by t1.column1` does

Comment: Thanks again, and using subquery in the select clause is basically just put the full second query inside the select clause like: "select Table1.column1 AS CODE, COUNT(DINSTINCT(Table2.column1 || '|' || Table2.column2)) AS COUNT, (full second query statement in the question) as idnumbers"?

Comment: Like: "select Table1.column1 AS CODE, 
    COUNT(DINSTINCT(Table2.column1 || '|' || Table2.column2)) AS COUNT, 
    (select Table3.column1
    FROM   Table3
    INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn
    WHERE .... 
    AND Table1.column1 = Table1.column1) as idnumbers
    FROM  Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.referenceColumn = Table2.referenceColumn WHERE ....
"?

Comment: @John: comments are not really meant for code (as you can see...). What you ask for seem like a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask); note that you should really provide sample data from your tables and expected results so you will get an accurate answer.